# How to embedded a canvas element onto the top of current webpage?

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

Trying to embed a canvas element top of current webpage in chrome extension, but it is not working.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.onload = drawOntoCanvas();
var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL("sandwich-48.png");
image.src = imgURL;
alert(imgURL);
function drawOntoCanvas() 
{
var testcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var testcontext = testcanvas.getContext('2d');

/// set size
testcanvas.width = 100;   /// "this" = image just loaded
testcanvas.height = 100;

testcontext.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
alert("In content script");
document.body.appendChild(testcanvas);
//testcanvas.parentNode.removeChild(testcanvas);
}
```

Sorry for my naivety Thanks in advance!!

Comment: give the canvas element a height and width, not to mention you are immediately removing it.

Comment: i also tried that with this "testcanvas.setattribute("width", "100") in my content script still not working.?

Comment: and append/prepend it to the body not the document or the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your image available in the context of a web-page, you need to declare it under **[web_accessible_resources](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html)** in your manifest.

---

A sample implementation would look like this:

**Extension files:**

```
          root-directory/
                      |_____manifest.json
                      |_____content.js
                      |_____someIcon.png
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"]
    }],

    "web_accessible_resources": ["someIcon.png"]
}
```

**content.js:**

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.onload = drawOntoCanvas;   // <-- no `()` when setting the callback
image.src = chrome.extension.getURL("someIcon.png");

function drawOntoCanvas() {
    var testcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var testcontext = testcanvas.getContext('2d');

    testcanvas.width = 100;
    testcanvas.height = 100;

    testcontext.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    document.body.appendChild(testcanvas);
}
```

Comment: "web_accessible_resources": ["sandwich-48.png"]: Yupp tried this too ... thanks for constantly upto helping me... but it's still not working.

Comment: I sure worked for me (see sample code above). Make sure you copy-paste my code, but **change the filenames** according to your file--and image-names. Have you scrolled all the way down to the page (because there is where the image will be drawn) ? Are all your files (and image) in the same top-level, directory ?

Comment: My all the files are in the same directory as all my content and background scripts.
And yes i am getting the image bottom of the page. Thanx
So can we add a large bunch of code here ?

Comment: You mean add a large bunch of code in the content-script ? Sure, why not ?